# Linq method based left join with multiple criteria

Tags: c#, linq

How i can obtain the similar Linq query as this SQL query using Linq method based?

```
SELECT * FROM F_ARTICLE A
LEFT JOIN F_ARTFOURNISS AF ON AF.AR_Ref = A.AR_Ref AND AF.AF_Principal = 1
ORDER BY A.AR_Design DESC 
OFFSET 500 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
```

I'm using method based due to System.Linq.Dynamic requirements.

The mapping is like this:
[image]

I started by this but i don't know how to limit to AF_Principal = 1:

```
var query = context.F_ARTICLE
            .Join(
                context.F_ARTFOURNISS,
                    a => a.AR_Ref,
                    t => t.AR_Ref,
                    (a, t) => new { a, t })
            .Select(
                z => new ArticleItem()
                {
                    Article = z.a,
                    Tarif = z.t.FirstOrDefault()
                })
            .OrderBy($"{field} {direction}");

return query.Skip(startIndex).Take(count).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the query:

```
var query = context.F_ARTICLE
            .GroupJoin(
                context.F_ARTFOURNISS,
                    a => a.AR_Ref,
                    t => t.AR_Ref,                                    
                    (a, t) => new { a, t })
            .Select(
                z => new ArticleItem()
                {
                    Article = z.a,
                    Tarif = z.t.Where(t=>t.AF_Principal == 1).FirstOrDefault()
                })
            .OrderBy($"{field} {direction}");

return query.Skip(startIndex).Take(count).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is from my head but the point is using `DefaultIfEmpty` for doing LEFT JOIN:

```
var query = from farticle in context.F_ARTICLE
        join b in context.F_ARTFOURNISS
        on new {farticle.AR_Ref, AF_Principal = 1} equals new {b.AR_Ref, b.AF_Principal} into gj
        from subres in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select farticle;

return query.Skip(startIndex).Take(count).ToList();
```

Also you can limit by `AF_Principal` using `Where` clause (I think DBMS engine will optimize the query anyway)

Comment: This is not a method based query

Comment: @ebelair you can change your `Join` to `ontext.F_ARTFOURNISS,
                    a => new {a.AR_Ref, AF_Principal = 1},
                    t => new {t.AR_Ref, t.AF_Principal},
                    (a, t) => new { a, t })` to limit `AF_Principal` to 1

Answer (score 0):

see if this works

```
 var query =   from F1 in context.F_ARTICLE join F2 in context.F_ARTFOURNISS
            on F1.AR_Ref equals F2.AR_Ref into newF
            from F3 in newF.where(f=>f.AF_Principal == 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select f;
            return query.Skip(startIndex).Take(count).ToList();
```

Comment: This is not a method based query